# Maximal value of directed graph with constraints

Tags: algorithms, graphs

What is an algorithm to calculate the maximum "score" possible in a directed graph, with the constraint that edges with the same value can only be traversed once? For example, in the graph below, given that you can use each of *a*, *b*, and *c* once, the best path is to use *a* and *b* to get to 7, and *c* to get to 2, for a score of 9.

[image]

**Edit:** This is another way to formulate the problem:
**Given:** A set $S$ of $(key:value)$ pairs, where the key itself is a non-empty set of variables, eg - $S = \{(\{a\}:2), (\{c\}:2), (\{a, b\}:7), (\{b\}:3), (\{c\}:1)\}$. Keys may not be unique, so the word 'key' may be misleading.
**Required:** A subset $S' \subseteq S$ such that the total sum of values of each member of $S'$ is maximized.
**Constraint:** Each variable present in any of the keys of $S$ (eg. $a, b$ etc.) belongs to the list (key) of exactly one member of $S'$
For example, $S' = \{(\{c\}:2), (\{a, b\}:7)\}$ has a total value of 9, and each of $a, b, c$ occur in exactly one list.

Comment: can you explain your problem in more detail ? how is the directed graph constructed ? and what do you want to obtain ? Tell us more about what is this problem applicable to.

Comment: Essentially, I have several workers that return proposals, that may be mutually exclusive.  They each pertain to a single value.  I.e.: "With a or c, I will provide 2." "With a and b I will provide 7." "With b, I will provide 3." "With c, I will provide 1."  Except that, of course, in my real domain it will be more complex.

Comment: This is similar to the problem solved e.g. by Dijkstra's algorithm (just that looks for minimal cost, not maximal benefit).

Comment: From your example, all you have to do is to compares the values of the leaves $O(|V|)$. Find the leaf $l$ with highest score, and find the path from $s$ to $l$ .. $O(h)$ , where $h$ is height of the tree (btw: is it a tree ? or it can be any general DAG ?). Am I getting right ?

Comment: I am looking for a *total* score--probably unclear, but you start at S repeatedly until your keys are exhausted.

Comment: how do you create the graph given above ? [give us more details]

Comment: You have to tell us how exactly the score is computed (for an arbitrary directed graph, that is also if it has cycles).

Comment: @Raphael As per my understanding, the graphs are misleading. I have tried to present the problem in a semi-formal way as an edit, based on the OP's comments.
syrion: please check if my formulation is what you mean.

Comment: it seems to me as the variation of the knapsack problem.

Comment: I think I see a $\Theta(n^2 \log n)$-time algorithm, would that suffice?

Comment: @Raphael: I'd be interested in the algorithm, since to me it seems that 3-dimensional matching can be reduced to this problem...

Comment: I think we can modify ford-fulkerson maximal flow algorithm to solve this problem